# Jersey client with null put method

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-client

I am working on a Jersey service client for one of my services and am having trouble determining the best way to pass a null entity through the client's put. On the service side of things this is my endpoint:

```
  @PUT
  @Path("/rule/disable/key/{key}")
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public Response disableRuleByKey(@PathParam("key") String key)
      throws Exception {
    try {
      DAL.getWriter().disableRuleByKey(key);
      return Response.ok().build();
    } catch (BlahException bla) {
      throw de;
  }
```

Basically all the method does in the backend is flip a toggle for other parts of the application to use. I'm not sure if put is the correct call to use here (but this was written by a teammate). I know it doesn't even have a JSON payload.

Anyways, on the client side I have this generic `putItem()` code for all of my clients to use via `extends`:

```
  public static <T> boolean putItem(Client client, String uri, T item)
      throws InterruptedException,
      ExecutionException {
    Invocation putConfig = client.target(uri).request()
        .buildPut(Entity.entity(item, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    Future<Response> asyncResponse = putConfig.submit();
    Response response = asyncResponse.get();

    return response.getStatus() == Status.OK.getStatusCode();
  }
```

This `PUT`s into the database fine with a JSON payload, but since the method above doesn't specifically have a payload I was wondering what the best course of action would be. Would modifying the Invocation's `.buildPut()` to have `null` in it be okay since I am not passing in a payload.

I am open to modifying the endpoint too but this is what I currently have and can't figure out the best way to send this value to the backend. Should I just modify the endpoint to consume a JSON object rather than passing the key as a `@PathParam`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When replacing the state of a resource with a [`PUT`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4) request, you should send the new representation in the request payload.

Have a look the the RFC 7231, the current reference for semantics and content in HTTP/1.1:

> [**4.3.4.  PUT**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4)
>
> The `PUT` method requests that the state of the target resource be created or replaced with the state defined by the representation enclosed in the request message payload. [...]

Comment: Cool. So does that then mean that Instead of the endpoint strictly using `@PathParam(String key)` it should just be `disableRuleByKey(String key)` and a cooresponding JSON payload?

Comment: @erp Yes. Use the URL to locate the resource and the payload of the request to send a new representation of the resource to the server.